# Add user to group but not reflected when run "id"

Tags: linux, unix

R creates a group called staff and I want to be able to update packages without starting R as sudo.  So I added myself to staff using:

```
sudo usermod -G adm,dialout,cdrom,plugdev,lpadmin,admin,sambashare,staff matt
```

(side question is there a way to add yourself to a group without listing every other group you're a member of?)

If i check /etc/groups i see

```
staff:x:50:matt
```

and the same for /etc/shadow

```
staff:*::matt
```

however if i run groups or id i'm not a member of staff.  Also, I can't make changes to anything in /usr/local/lib/R.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Did you log the "matt" account out and back in after running the `sudo usermod` command?  Changes to the groups a user is in under unix only take affect at login time.

Comment: Thanks.  It was weird though b/c I could remove and readd to other groups that I was already a member of the changes were reflected.

Comment: beware that if you  are login in via `ssh` and you have `ControlMaster` the connection will be kept open and reused so you will not see the groups either. To force a real new loging in those cases you need to `ssh -O exit hostname` to kill the ssh shared connection first

Comment: That was my problem. I suggest using `-O stop`, which won't kill existing SSH session while still creating a new connection for the next session.

Answer (score 19):

https://superuser.com/questions/272061/reload-a-linux-users-group-assignments-without-logging-out

check that out ~

both

```
newgrp groupname
```

OR

```
su - username
```

will do the trick well ~

Comment: Instead of `newgrp groupname`, I would recommend to use a simple **`newgrp -`** which reinitialize the user's environment.

Answer (score 5):

In answer to your side question, yes you can add a user to a group without listing them all. If you run a Debian based system, you can do it with

`sudo adduser matt staff`

The  `adduser` utility is just a friendly wrapper around useradd/usermod etc.

If you don't have the `adduser` utility, you can still do it with usermod:

`sudo usermod -a -G staff matt`

The `-a` flag means append (as opposed to overwrite).

Comment: Note that the ``usermod`` utility can be used on Debian as well as others distributions such as Archlinux and thus is prefered when working on a script for multiple distributions.

Answer (score 0):

I know the original question is for Linux but OSX users can do the same with this command:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a newusertoadd -t user grouptobeaddedto
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**: The operation succeeded - that's why your name appears in the right linux files on `/etc/passwd` & `/etc/group` but as soon as you open a new terminal process the bash will be updated with this setting and you can perform `id matt` as well.

**Clarification**: You added yourself to additional group so you should have used append option `-a` (and not editing the all bunch of groups names to your user).

```
sudo usermod -aG staff matt
```