# Pycharm Docker Unix / TCP socket (with unix:///var/run/docker.sock): Permission Denied

Tags: sockets, docker, pycharm

I get a Permission Denied error when trying to setup Docker in PyCharm Professional edition. I'm on Debian Jessie (BunsenLabs).

```
Cannot connect: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: connect(..) failed: Permission denied: /var/run/docker.sock
caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connect(..) failed: Permission denied
```

It happens with both the default settings (using Unix socket) and with the TCP socket, Engine API URL = `unix:///var/run/docker.sock` (does it make sense?).

If we look at the permissions on the socket:

```
$ ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Jul  5 11:18 /var/run/docker.sock
```

We see that its owned by root and the docker group.

So I tried to add my user to the docker group (with `sudo usermod -a -G docker USERNAME`), and restarted the Docker service (with `sudo service docker restart`), but it still does not work.

One way to allow PyCharm to use the socket is to run it with root permissions, i.e. `sudo pycharm`, but I would like to avoid this. I was also able to fix this by setting read and write permissions for others on the socket (`sudo chmod o+rw /var/run/docker.sock`) but now everybody can use Docker on that machine without admin privilege.

What is the most secure way to allow PyCharm to connect to the Docker socket?

Also, please note that Docker works fine on the command-line. Before the quick-and-dirty-fix (`chmod o+rw`), I had to use `sudo docker`, and had updated `/etc/sudoers` to not type the password for this command. Now it works even without `sudo`. It does not feel secure, but it's a development machine so if there is no other solution, I'll keep it like that.

**EDIT:** I am adding additional, important information.

First, adding my user in the Docker group was indeed the way to go. The thing is that when using `sudo usermod`, changes are not immediately reflected for the user account you are using. **You need to log out and log in again to refresh the system.** More information in this post and answer: [Add user to group but not reflected when run "id"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537197/add-user-to-group-but-not-reflected-when-run-id#7537275).

Secondly, adding yourself in the Docker group **allows privilege escalation!** Any user being able to run `docker` without `sudo` (and therefore without typing a password) will also be able to run a container with the root of the system mounted in a volume: `docker run -v /:/host_root -it --rm ubuntu /bin/bash`. Since you are root in the container, it means you can manipulate the host system **as if you were root on the host**. Please take this into consideration before adding users in the docker group.

Comment: Is your docker working properly outside PyCharm? Meaning - is there no permissions issue when trying to access the docker daemon from bash?

Comment: I previously stated this in my question and removed it, but yes, Docker works like a charm in the command-line! I will add this back.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I assume, your username is already in docker group. To check this, issue below command.

```
id -nG
```

If not, you need to add your user into the docker group by below command.

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

When you execute the command, `sudo systemctl start docker`, it creates a docker process. That docker process contains `dockerd` daemon thread. The command also creates default `docker.sock` Unix socket. The `docker.sock` socket is continuously listened by `dockerd` daemon thread. This makes you can do kernel-level IPC with `docker.pid` process. To be able to use this docker socket, you need to have proper permission from the process level (`docker.pid`) and file level (`docker.sock`). So, executing below two commands should solve your issue.

```
sudo chmod a+rwx /var/run/docker.sock
sudo chmod a+rwx /var/run/docker.pid
```

As you see, it doesn't show any error in PyCharm. 
[image]

Note: running `sudo dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock` also does the same thing as above explained.

Furthermore, you can create TCP socket so that you can use this TCP socket for your own host as well as for any remote hosts.

**docker stop:** `sudo systemctl stop docker`

`dockerd -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 -H` //you should stop docker before executing this command

**start the docker:** `sudo systemctl start docker`

And, see below successful TCP docker socket connection in PyCharm.
[image]

Comment: Accepted this answer instead of mine, it is more complete. Mine was just an update. I added two notes as an edit in my post instead.

Comment: This saved me, thank you so much! I was pulling my hair out

Answer (score 2):

Another option worth trying is to expose your docker daemon over localhost tcp inferface - [ref](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#configuring-remote-access-with-daemonjson)

Reffering to the docs, you can write your `/etc/docker/daemon.json` so that looks like:

```
{
"hosts": ["unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "tcp://127.0.0.1:2375"]
}
```

With that setup, you can try restarting docker and configure a `TCP socket` in PyCharm preferences.

Comment: I did not previously have `/etc/docker/daemon.json` so I created it and wrote these exact same contents, but now Docker won't start. I have a message like `docker.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.` in the logs... Maybe it was because of conky trying to run docker commands. Will try again after reboot.

Comment: So! I went for the configuration of the systemd service instead: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#configuring-remote-access-with-systemd-unit-file. I still had to give it a bit more than a minute before being able to restart: `let time=5; until service docker start; do sleep $time; echo slept $time; let time+=$time; done`. Worked after time=40. But! It's in fact now working with `srw-rw---- 1 root docker /var/run/docker.sock` and my user being in the docker group. I think it needed a reboot. Before the reboot, `groups` did not show "docker". Now it does. TIL a lot!

Comment: Anyway thank you for the suggestion, I tested it and it worked as well!

Comment: Note that doing this will give every user and process on the local system unrestricted root access.  `chmod 0777 /var/run/docker.sock` is no more or less dangerous but at least doesn't also open up the TCP socket.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that my first attempt (to add myself in the `docker` group) was the right one. But it needed a reboot.

Indeed, I was suprised not to see "docker" in the output of the `groups` command. After the reboot, it now shows "docker".

I reset the socket permission to what they were before: `sudo chmod o-rw /var/run/docker.sock`.

PyCharm is able to connect to the socket successfully.

Comment: Good to hear it finally worked. Strange though because I never needed a restart on Debians/Ubuntus after doing these post-install steps you described. That's why I thought we need to find a new solution ;)

Comment: Ah! Just found an explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537197/add-user-to-group-but-not-reflected-when-run-id#7537275 :)